# Xml Parsing with Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-parsing, windows-phone, linq-to-xml

I am working on Windows Phone 8 app development.

i have a xml like the below:

```
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>SubTopics</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>ID</key>
                <array>
                    <string>CD1</string>
                    <string>CD2</string>
                    <string>CD3</string>
                    <string>CD4</string>    
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Miscellaneous</string>
                <key>Desc</key>
                <string> this is just a text</string>
                <key>HasItems</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>ID</key>
                <array>
                    <string>DDC1</string>
                    <string>DDC2</string>
                    <string>DDC3</string>
                    <string>DDC4</string>
                    <string>DDC5</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Miscellaneous One</string>
                <key>Desc</key>
                <string> this is just a text</string>
                <key>HasItems</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
      </array>
      <key>MainTitle</key>
      <string>Data</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>SubTopics</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>ID</key>
                <array>
                    <string>SSD1</string>
                    <string>SS2</string>
                    <string>SS3</string>
                    <string>SS4</string>    
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Goblins</string>
                <key>Desc</key>
                <string> this is just a text</string>
                <key>HasItems</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>ID</key>
                <array>
                    <string>ADC1</string>
                    <string>ADC2</string>
                    <string>ADC3</string>
                    <string>ADC4</string>
                    <string>DDC5</string>
                </array>
                <key>Title</key>
                <string>Tracks</string>
                <key>Desc</key>
                <string> this is just a text</string>
                <key>HasItems</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
      </array>
      <key>MainTitle</key>
      <string>Data Two</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

How to parse this ?

Its like this :

```
MainTitle 

   --SubTitle // list of title 

  ---ID

  ---Desc

  ---Boolean Value
 MainTitle 

   --SubTitle //list of values

  ---ID

  ---Desc

  ---Boolean Value
```

Now in 1st screen i am displaying all the Main Titles

Now on click of Main tile in 1st screen i need all the values of that main title.

So how can i store these a `Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>` ?

**EDIT**

I have tried this:

```
var dict = (from plist in doc.Root.Element("array").Elements("dict")
                          select new MyObject
                          {
                              MainTitle = (string)plist.Element("string"),
                              ListOfSubTitles = plist.Element("array")
                                                   .Elements("dict")
                                                   .Elements("string")
                                                   .Select(s => (string)s)
                                                   .ToList(),
                          })
                         .ToDictionary(a => a.MainTitle, a => a.ListOfSubTitles);
```

But here its also storing the Desc tag values also in the `ListOfSubTitles`

Comment: Have you tried parsing this xml? Can you show your attempt?

Comment: Ask to your class mate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146447/linq-to-xml-with-nested-dictionary-and-array#comment33605276_22146447 And i am pertty sure this is at least the 3rd one. No one making the homework by himself anymore?

Comment: @L.B it was my collegue who is working from other country

Comment: @user3114009 And you decided to ask here instead of him?

Comment: @L.B he has so i have taken this task and i have tried it but i am not able to achieve the required result, so instead of provoking other not to help me, please help me to find a soultion

Comment: @L.B i told you he is not here,he works from different country so its obvious that there will be a time difference

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy You saw my edit ? thats the issue there

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you removed your answer ?

Comment: @user3114009 How many collegues do you have who works on the same topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21980457/parsing-inner-tag-with-its-value ? At least 3 people just to parse a silly xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use helper methods. First one is to create dictionary of values from your strange xml data format (it uses `key` element value as dictionary entry key, and next node as dictionary entry value):

```
static Dictionary<string, XElement> GetValues(XElement dict)
{
    return dict.Elements("key")
               .ToDictionary(k => (string)k, k => (XElement)k.NextNode);
}
```

Second one is parsing `MyObject`:

```
static MyObject ParseMyObject(XElement dict)
{
    var values = GetValues(dict);

    return new MyObject
    {
        MainTitle = (string)values["Title"],
        ListOfSubTitles = values["ID"].Elements().Select(s => (string)s).ToList()
    };
}
```

All parsing will look like:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var result = 
    xdoc.Root.Elements("dict")
        .Select(GetValues)
        .ToDictionary(v => (string)v["MainTitle"],
                      v => v["SubTopics"]
                              .Elements("dict").Select(ParseMyObject).ToList());
```

Result of parsing:

```
{
  "Data": [
    {
      MainTitle: "Miscellaneous",
      ListOfSubTitles: [ "CD1", "CD2", "CD3", "CD4" ]
    },
    {
      MainTitle: "Miscellaneous One",
      ListOfSubTitles: [ "DDC1", "DDC2", "DDC3", "DDC4", "DDC5" ]
    }
  ],
  "Data Two": [
    {
      MainTitle: "Goblins",
      ListOfSubTitles: [ "SSD1", "SS2", "SS3", "SS4" ]
    },
    {
      MainTitle: "Tracks",
      ListOfSubTitles: [ "ADC1", "ADC2", "ADC3", "ADC4", "DDC5" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I will try this and let you know please wait

Comment: It should be Data, SubTopics , Data Two Subtopics

Comment: We are going to display Data and Data Two in the 1st screen, on Tap of Data i need to get all the Subtopics, and again on click of each subtopc i need to get all the ID

Comment: Ok, thanks give me 2 mins i will try once, and also now i can assing Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>> dicts = xdoc.Root.Elements("dict")... right ?

Comment: @user3114009 yes, result is `Dictionary<string, List<MyObject>>`

Comment: i am try to display the values in console but its not displaying here is my code :foreach (var value in dictss)
            {

                // use value.Key and value.Value
                Debug.WriteLine("key is "+value.Key+ " value counnt is "+value.Value.Count);

                for (int j = 0; j < value.Value.Count; j++)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("subtopics are "+value.Value[j]);
                }
            }
Do you find anything wrong here ? here dictss is the Dictionary

Comment: Its not displaying anything ? after using for loop also ,am i doing anything wrong ?

Comment: one more thing, at the end ihave <dict> without MainTitle tag, so for me its showing Null reference there, but that should be added to topic  object, how to do it ?