# Parsing Xml document by moving to each NodeType

Tags: c#, wpf, xml-parsing, windows-phone

I am trying to parse xml and assign that to object:

XML file:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict>
    <key>SubTitle</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>IDs</key>
            <array>
                <string>CD1</string>
                <string>CD2</string>
                <string>CD3</string>
            </array>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Data One</string>
            <key>ABC</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>XYZ</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>HasLessons</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>IDs</key>
            <array>
                <string>DDC1</string>
                <string>DDC2</string>
                <string>DDC3</string>
            </array>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>Data Two</string>
            <key>ABC</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>XYZ</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>HasLessons</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>MainTitle</key>
    <string>Collection of Data</string>
</dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I have tried to parse like this :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FileName);
            XElement plist = doc.Element("plist");
            XElement array = plist.Element("array");

            int topicID = 0;
            Topic topic = new Topic();

            String keyValue = String.Empty;

            topicCollection = new List<Topic>();

            using (XmlReader reader = array.CreateReader())
            {
                reader.MoveToContent();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "dict")
                        {
                            topicID++;
                            topic = new Topic();
                            topic.TopicID = topicID;
                            topicCollection.Add(topic);
                        }
                        else if (reader.Name == "key")
                        {
                            if (!reader.Read())
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text || reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
                            {
                                keyValue = reader.Value;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (reader.Name == "string")
                        {
                            if (!reader.Read())
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else if (topic != null && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text || reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.CDATA)
                            {
                                switch (keyValue)
                                {
                                    case "Title":
                                        topic.SubTitle = reader.Value;
                                        break;
                                    case "IDs":
                                        topic.FileNames.Add(reader.Value);
                                        break;
                                    case "ABC":
                                        topic.ABC = int.Parse(reader.Value);
                                        break;
                                    case "XYZ":
                                        topic.XYZ = reader.Value;
                                        break;
                                    case "MainTitle":
                                        topic.MainTitle = reader.Value;
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.EndElement)
                    {
                        if (reader.Name == "dict" && topic != null)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

What am i doing wrong here ?
I am trying to display all the Main Title in first screen then onclick of each main title display list of subtitles and on click on each subtitle display list of ids.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146447/linq-to-xml-with-nested-dictionary-and-array and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156794/xml-parsing-with-dictionarystring-listmyobject

Comment: Just wondering - why you are creating XDocument but using XmlReader? And even more interesting question - why you don't use solution from question which you asked yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156794/xml-parsing-with-dictionarystring-listmyobject

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I am sorry to say this, but when i tried to print the values its not printing anything, and also i guess this is one more way that i have tried to acheive the result

Comment: @user3114009 I provided you sample output - xml which you have was parsed successfully. So either you have different xml, or you have problems with displaying your data. I suggest to set breakpoint in debugger and check what data you have in dictionary *before* trying to display them

Comment: I appreciate your help, but still stuck without a soultion and time is ticking

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Please see my edit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22156794/xml-parsing-with-dictionarystring-listmyobject

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy you saw my edit ?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Are you there ?

Comment: @user3114009 I have seen it and rolled back. Do not modify your original questions, especially that dramatically. So, have done what I said to you in my previous comment? Can you post screenshot from debugger?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48934/discussion-between-user3114009-and-sergey-berezovskiy)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Parsing the XML have to considered to use the Serialization  .. you have have a class having data members which corresponds to the nodes in you XML and then once that is done you can simple  de serialize your XML into the object and use that in your code ?
A dedicated XML serializer is present in which can be used for this. If you want to control how you serialize then you can also use the ISearizable interface.